# How to use DrMemory to display and report a memory leak in C++?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks

I am trying to use DrMemory as it seems to be an easy to use Windows Memory Leaking detection tool: http://www.drmemory.org/

I purposely created the c++ app below that might have a memory leak.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Dog{
public:
    int a;
    string b;
    Dog()
    {
        a = 1;
        b = "alfred";
    }

    ~Dog()
    {

    }
};

class Example{
public:
    Dog* d1;
    Dog* d2;
    string a;
    int b;

    Example()
    {
        a = "test";
        b = 15;
        d1 = new Dog();
        d2 = new Dog();
    }

    ~Example()
    {
        //delete d;
    }

};

void createObjects(){
    for(unsigned int i=0; i < 200; i++)
    {
        Dog* d = new Dog();
        Example* b = new Example();
    }

    Dog* d = new Dog();
    d = NULL;
    Example* b = new Example();
    b = NULL;
}

int main()
{
    createObjects();
    return 0;
}
```

---

After building this app along with the following options (as instructed by DrMemory documentation) **"-ggdb -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++"** , I executed the executable with drmemory.exe, like this:

***drmemory.exe TestingDrMemory.exe***

However, I am not seeing any error/log message related to the memory leak and I am unable to identify the line in the source code that this occurs. Is this possible in DrMemory? What is the correct way to use this in order to identify/detect lines in the source code that cause the memory leak?

The log is below:

---

```
Dr. Memory version 1.7.0 build 5 built on Apr  4 2014 23:38:05
Dr. Memory results for pid 18240: "TestingDrMemory.exe"
Application cmdline: "TestingDrMemory.exe"
Recorded 104 suppression(s) from default C:\Program Files (x86)\Dr. Memory\bin\suppress-default.txt

===========================================================================
FINAL SUMMARY:

DUPLICATE ERROR COUNTS:

SUPPRESSIONS USED:

NO ERRORS FOUND:
      0 unique,     0 total unaddressable access(es)
      0 unique,     0 total uninitialized access(es)
      0 unique,     0 total invalid heap argument(s)
      0 unique,     0 total GDI usage error(s)
      0 unique,     0 total handle leak(s)
      0 unique,     0 total warning(s)
      0 unique,     0 total,      0 byte(s) of leak(s)
      0 unique,     0 total,      0 byte(s) of possible leak(s)
      0 unique,     0 total,      0 byte(s) of still-reachable allocation(s)
ERRORS IGNORED:
      2 potential error(s) (suspected false positives)
         (details: C:\Dr. Memory\DrMemory-TestingDrMemory.exe.18240.000\potential_errors.txt)
     18 potential leak(s) (suspected false positives)
         (details: C:\Dr. Memory\DrMemory-TestingDrMemory.exe.18240.000\potential_errors.txt)
Details: C:\Dr. Memory\DrMemory-TestingDrMemory.exe.18240.000\results.txt
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is for SO, as it's about how to use a specific too. However it does seem like a good question otherwise, as your code is clearly full of leaks and it's not showing them (although there are ignored errors).

Comment: If we are talking about specific tools I would suggest Deleaker that is known for years.

Answer (score -1):

From the [drmemory.org](https://drmemory.org/page_prep.html)

> If your application links with a static library that was built with frame pointer optimizations and you observe missing frames on your callstacks, try running with the Dr. Memory runtime options -no_callstack_use_top_fp, -no_callstack_use_fp, and -callstack_conservative. These will add some additional overhead on malloc-intensive applications, but should eliminate skipped frames.

Try running drmem with `-batch -no_callstack_use_fp -no_callstack_use_top_fp`